# Cron pattern with start and end time with minute

Tags: unix, cron

I want a job a to execute every `15 mins` starting from `10:30 AM` to `8:30 PM`.

I tried `30/15 10-20 * * *`. But it ignores the times `11:00 AM`, `11:15 AM`, `12:00 PM`, `12:15 PM`, `1:00 PM`, `1:15 PM` etc.

I would like to know the proper cron string for the above expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Run command every fifteen minutes between 10:30 and 20:30.
0,15,30,45 11-19 * * * …command…
30,45      10    * * * …command…
0,15,30    20    * * * …command…
```

The first line deals with the whole hours from 11:00 to 19:45.  The second line handles 10:30 and 10:45.  The third line handles 20:00, 20:15, 20:30 (assuming you want it to run at 20:30 too — if you don't the fix is obvious).

It may not be beautiful, but it will get the job done.  Just make sure the `…command…` sequence is simple enough that the repetition is obvious.

You can probably replace the first component of the first line with `0/15` in your `cron`.  You might use `30/15` for the second one, but it doesn't seem any clearer than what's written anyway.  I'm not sure there's a good way to replace the other line.

One other possibility is to refactor it so that the hour range for each quarter hour is specified:

```
0  11-20 * * * …command…
15 11-20 * * * …command…
30 10-20 * * * …command…
45 10-19 * * * …command…
```

You could optionally combine the first two of those.

Comment: Hmm. So I'll have to write multiple cron patterns. Not possible from a single one..??

Comment: I don't know of a way, but I've not studied modern `crontab` formats in detail.  What I wrote would work in a 7th Edition Unix (1979) `cron` too (there wasn't a separate `crontab` command back then!).  To me, it causes no pain; I would specify a simple shell script (e.g. `/root/cron/specific-task.sh`) in the `crontab` entry and that script would contain any complexity.  In my book, what's in the `crontab` file or entry should be as simple as possible, but not simpler.  If you need to specify the shell, so be it: `sh /root/cron/specific-task.sh`.